# File can not be open after exporting grid to excel

Tags: asp.net, excel

I want to export grid to excel. Everything is working fine if the grid has 100 or less rows. But my grid has more than 2000 rows. I am not getting any error or exception but file is not opening after exporting and Excel gets stopped working. When I open file I am getting one warning message like "The file format and extension of 'filename.xls' don't match. The file could be corrupted or unsafe. Unless you trust its source, don't open it. Do you want to open it anyway ?".

I am using below code

```
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename=   {0}", "IAParts.xls"));
        Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
        System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
        BindGrid();//this method binds the data to grid
        GridView1.RenderControl(htw);
        Response.Write(sw.ToString());
        sw.Flush();
        Response.End();
```

Comment: The cause if this error is this line of code...HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw); You are outputting html and Excel does not recognize it as a native format. You can try adding this...Response.ContentType = "text/csv; charset-UTF-8", You will then need to apply the styling to the Excel file, not the output content since CSV does not provide fro formatting. I am facing the same issue and have not yet found an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 0):

dear friend for your error about extension file i can say that is about Extension Hardening that can be solved by looking at this link

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsofficedeveloper/archive/2008/03/11/excel-2007-extension-warning.aspx

or use this lines in txt file and save as .reg but these lines can be change with your versions and needs [i wrote these lines for my use]

[start]

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Excel\Security]
"ExtensionHardening"=dword:00000000

[end]

after that you will never see error about Extension or ...
and for using excel file I offer you this function that i searched and used in my projects ;)

```
public void ExportToExcel(DataTable dt)
    {
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            System.IO.StringWriter tw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
            System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter hw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(tw);
            DataGrid dgGrid = new DataGrid();
            dgGrid.DataSource = dt;
            dgGrid.DataBind();
            dgGrid.RenderControl(hw);
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"; // 2003 office excel
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=OutPut.xls");
            string style = @"<style> TABLE { border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; } TD {mso-number-format:\@; }</style> ";
            Response.Write(style);
            Response.Write(tw.ToString());
            Response.End();
        }
    }
```