# file format error while creating excel file

Tags: c#, export-to-excel

I have used some code to write excel in C#. I am exporting some data to excel but it generates error while opening this excel file. Can anyone help me to get rid from this.

Error dialog while opening excel file:

"The file format and extension of .xls don't match. the file could be corrupted or unsafe. unless you trust its source don't open it."

My code is below.

```
public string attachment = "attachment; filename=Data" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyhhmmss") + ".xls";

public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
{
     base.VerifyRenderingInServerForm(control);
}
 private void ExportGridView()
    {
        lblExportError.Text = "";
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
        Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";

        //Fetch database records

        DataTable dtData = GetURLData(Sitename);

        string strHTML = "";
        strHTML = strHTML + "<table border='1' width='100%'>";

        strHTML = strHTML + "<tr>";
        strHTML = strHTML + "<td><b>#</b></td>";
        strHTML = strHTML + "<td><b>Row ID</b></td>";
        strHTML = strHTML + "<td><b>Product Id</b></td>";
        strHTML = strHTML + "<td><b>Variation Id</b></td>";
        strHTML = strHTML + "<td><b>Score</b></td>";
        strHTML = strHTML + "<td><b>Old URL | New URL</b></td>";
        strHTML = strHTML + "</tr>";

        if (dtData.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            int index = 1;
            foreach (DataRow dr in dtData.Rows)
            {
                strHTML = strHTML + "<tr>";

                strHTML = strHTML + "<td>" + Convert.ToString(index) + "." + "</td>";
                strHTML = strHTML + "<td>" + Convert.ToString(dr["Id"]) + "</td>";
                strHTML = strHTML + "<td>" + Convert.ToString(dr["ProductId"]) + "</td>";
                strHTML = strHTML + "<td>" + Convert.ToString(dr["VariationId"]) + "</td>";
                strHTML = strHTML + "<td>" + Convert.ToString(dr["Score"]) + "</td>";
                strHTML = strHTML + "<td>" + Convert.ToString(dr["URL"]) + " | " + Convert.ToString(dr["NewURL"]) + "</td>";

                strHTML = strHTML + "</tr>";
                index++;
            }
        }
        else
            lblExportError.Text = "Oops! empty dataset.";

        strHTML = strHTML + "</table>";

        Response.Write(strHTML);

        Response.End();
    }
```

Comment: The fact that you've set `Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";` doesn't means it will be excel file. In fact you're writing usual *html table* to your response stream, not an excel file at all. For it to be excel file you need to create real excel workbook (for example, using NPOI library) and write its bytes into stream.

Comment: see this if can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24670071/file-can-not-be-open-after-exporting-grid-to-excel